# How can I remove each line if first symbol after quotation marks is dot?

Tags: sed

I need to remove each line from configuration if first symbol after quotes is dot in example:

```
local-zone: ".test.com" redirect <- remove
local-zone: "www.test.com" redirect <- don't remove
local-zone: "test.com" redirect <- don't remove
```

I've tried using sed but no success for me:

```
sed -i '/".*\..*"/d' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `sed`, you have `grep` too ;)

```
$ grep -Ev  '"\.[^"]+"' file .txt | sponge file.txt
local-zone: "www.test.com" redirect <- don't remove
local-zone: "test.com" redirect <- don't remove
```

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -i -E '/"\.[^"]+"/d' file
local-zone: "www.test.com" redirect <- don't remove
local-zone: "test.com" redirect <- don't remove
```

Comment: Ouch, works like a charm. Thank you